# Let $a=b+2$. suppose the sum of $a$ and $b$ is equal to the product of $a$ and $b$. Prove that $a$ and $b $are not integers

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Question.
Let $a=b+2$. suppose the sum of $a$ and $b$ is equal to the product of $a$ and $b$. Prove that $a$ and $b$ are not integers.

Any help is very much appreciated!

Comment: Write down equations for $a$ and $b$, then solve them.

Comment: It is advised to give your attempt to solve

Answer (score 5):

**Hint**:

Write the relation

> The sum of $a$ and $b$ is equal to the product of $a$ and $b$

as an equation.

Comment: Gangster answer:)

Answer (score 0):

We have $a=b+2$, then $(b+2)+b=(b+2)b$. After simplification, $b^2=2$.

---

As

$$1<b^2<4$$ we must have $$1<b<2,$$ which is impossible.

Answer (score -1):

$ab=a+b$

$b(b+2)=2b+2$

$b^2=2$

This has solutions $2^{1/2}$ and $-2^{1/2}$, which are not integers.

Answer (score -1):

$a+b = ab$ and $a=b+2$

substitute $a$
$$(b+2) + b = (b+2)b$$
$$2b + 2 = b^2 + 2b$$
$$b = \pm\sqrt{2}$$
$b$ is irrational, not an integer.
As $a = b + 2$
$$a = 2 \pm \sqrt{2}$$
thus $a$ is also irrational and not an integer.

Comment: Why was this down voted?